# Função termina antes de pedir o valor do scanf

Tags: c

Alguém consegue perceber porque é que quando na função aceitarUtilizadores chamo o main(), o main() não executar o scan? Ou seja, quando chamo novamente o main não me deixa escolher nenhuma opçao e encerra logo o programa. Obrigado

```
void main(){

int j=0;
char opcao;

FILE *pedidos;

pedidos=fopen("../Projeto/Login/Users/pedidos", "r");


char leitor[100000];                             //listar o primeiro pedido de novo registo

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        fgets(leitor,10000,pedidos);
        printf("%s", leitor);
    }
    printf("Pretende autorizar o registo deste utilizador? (y/n):");
    scanf("%c", &opcao);

    switch(opcao){
        case 'y':
        aceitarUtilizadores();
        break;
        case 'n':
        //rejeitarUtilizador();
        break;
    }


    }
void aceitarUtilizadores(){

char leitor[100];

FILE*ativos, *pedidos, *temp;

pedidos=fopen("../Projeto/Login/Users/pedidos", "r");

ativos=fopen("../Projeto/Login/Users/UserData", "a");

temp=fopen("../Projeto/Login/Users/temp", "w");

for(int i=0; i<5;i++){ 

        fgets(leitor,100,pedidos);

        fputs(leitor,ativos);
    }

    while((fgets(leitor,100,pedidos))!=NULL){ //escreve os restantes pedidos para um ficheiro temporario
        fputs(leitor,temp);
    }
    fclose(pedidos);
    fclose(ativos);
    fclose(temp);
    temp=fopen("../Projeto/Login/Users/temp","r");
    pedidos=fopen("../Projeto/Login/Users/pedidos","w"); //abre o ficheiro dos pedidos apagando o seu conteudo

    while((fgets(leitor,100,temp))!=NULL){ //copia os pedidos que faltam ser analisados para o ficheiro de pedidos
        fputs(leitor,pedidos);
    }
    remove("../Projeto/Login/Users/temp");
    fclose(pedidos);
    pedidos=fopen("../Projeto/Login/Users/pedidos", "r");
    rewind(pedidos);
    system("clear");
    if((fgets(leitor,100,pedidos))!=NULL){
        fclose(pedidos);
        main();
    }



    fclose(pedidos);
}
```

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta. Você quer que depois que retornar da função 'aceitarUtilizador()', o programa volte para o 'main()' pedindo se o usuário quer aceitar ou não o registro? Em outras palavras, você quer que o programa volte na linha: printf("Pretende autorizar o registo deste utilizador? (y/n):");   ???

Comment: Ola, também não compreendi muito sua pergunta, ao compilar qual foi o erro? Posso estar errado, mas se você estiver usando o Windows por exemplo ele não aceita o comando system("clear"), talvez seja isso, mas mande qual o erro ou clarear suas dúvidas. Valeuu

Comment: Figboy tentou trocar o scanf por getch ou getche?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As vezes fica uma espécie de "lixo" no buffer do teclado que é quando você aperta o enter, aí ao entrar no próximo `scanf` ele recebe esse enter novamente e pra ele é como se já tivesse inserido um valor, para resolver você pode usar essa linha antes do scanf `fflush(stdin);` (No windows, no Linux é outro comando, se não me engano) ou apenas dê um espaço dentro das aspas do `scanf` que também funciona: `scanf(" %d", &seuInt);`, por padrão eu sempre dou esse espaço dentro do `scanf` para não precisar usar o `fflush`, uso o `fflush` apenas antes de `getchar()`

Comment: Era exatamente isso que estava a acontecer, ao mudar scanf("%c", &opcao); para scanf(" %c", &opcao); resolveu o problema

Comment: fico feliz em ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Pretende autorizar o registo deste utilizador? (y/n):");
scanf("%s", &opcao);
```

amigo recente tive um problema semelhante ao seu, resolvi mudando no scanf("%c") para scanf("%s").

Não custa tentar ai, boa sorte.